# How to fix javascript countdown seconds bug

Tags: javascript, html

so I have this countdown timer I created,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var interval;
    var minutes = 12;
    var seconds = 32;
    window.onload = function() {
        countdown('countdown');
}

function countdown(element) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {               
                minutes=7;
seconds=47;
                } else {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 60;
                }
            }
            if(minutes > 0) {
                var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ':' : ':');
            } else {
                var minute_text = '';
            }
            var second_text = seconds > 1 ?'':'';
            el.innerHTML = minute_text + ''+seconds + ' '+second_text + ' remaining';
            seconds--;
        }, 1000);

}
</script>
```

The result works perfectly, but when the timer reaches digits below 10, (12:03, 12:05, etc.) it displays the seconds without a '0' in the front. (12:3 instead of 12:03)

I tried fixing this, but it has brought me nowhere. Is it possible to somehow edit my script to fix this bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
second_text = (seconds > 9) ? (seconds) : ('0' + seconds);
```

Comment: s = seconds, i copied it from a countdown-script i wrote :)

Comment: I understood that, but OP might not. +1 for easiest answer.

Answer (score 1):

A number does not have a zero in front of it.

You have to manually add that.

```
if(seconds < 10) {
    second_text = "0" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: I know, but I have no idea where to add that line of code. I tried adding "0" between the line which combines the minutes and the seconds, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should never use parseInt like that.

Comment: @Neal btw you don't need to call parseInt on `second_text` because you already have access to `seconds`.

Comment: @sachleen lol I was under the impression that seconds was a total. not a real number. updating.

Comment: @Neal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix

Answer (score 1):

I just cleaned your code a bit:

```
var interval,
    minutes = 12,
    seconds = 32;

window.onload = function() {
    countdown('countdown');
}

function countdown(element) {
    var el = document.getElementById(element),
        minutes_text, second_text;

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                minutes=7;
                seconds=47;
            }
            else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }

        minutes_text = minutes;
        second_text = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

        el.innerHTML = minutes_text + ':' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a function to pad the value displayed

```
function padvalue(i) {
    if (i<10) {
        i="0" + String(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Call it here

```
el.innerHTML = minute_text + '' + padvalue(seconds) + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet to convert the numbers to strings:

```
var secondStr = seconds + "";
while (secondStr.length < 2) {
    secondStr = "0" + secondStr;
}
```

Do the same thing for minutes and hours and then print the strings.

(You do know that doing an interval of 1000 means the interval will be 1000 or more milliseconds? It's unlikely that you miss a whole tick though with that long of an interval. This means the counter will be close to real time seconds but not exact and will vary from time to time and computer to computer.)